# What would be the fastest way to concatenate three files in C#?

Tags: c#, file

I need to concatenate 3 files using C#. A header file, content, and a footer file, but I want to do this as cool as it can be done.

Cool = really small code or really fast (non-assembly code).

Comment: "Cool" code sounds dangerously close to "clever" code.  It might be a interesting novelty but if its harder to read, maintain, debug, test, etc its not worth it in the long run.

Comment: there is no assembly code in C#...

Comment: Yes, but you can use assembly code in a C# program

Comment: The code won't be the bottleneck, instead the way you talk to the disk will be. Don't write cool code. Write easy to read and maintain code. That's cooler!

Comment: "really small code or really fast" -- am I the only one who thinks that doesn't sound right?

Comment: @BobbyBruckovnic Try with multithreading , create 2 thread -  while reading of 2nd file by thread 1 your 2nd thread can write 1st file data parallelly .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
void CopyStream(Stream destination, Stream source) {
   int count;
   byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
   while( (count = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
       destination.Write(buffer, 0, count);
}


CopyStream(outputFileStream, fileStream1);
CopyStream(outputFileStream, fileStream2);
CopyStream(outputFileStream, fileStream3);
```

Comment: i don't find this so smart. What is a good BUFFER_SIZE? nobody knows. compared to File.ReadAllText(a) + File.ReadAllText(b) + File.ReadAllText(c), this looks like premature optimization to me.

Comment: Depends on the size of your files.  You would not like to concatenate a few hundred megabytes using the ReadAllText method.

Comment: I agree. But in such cases, I would really leave such a task to the experts that wrote a library or, as would cross my thoughs, the cat program. I would certainly not read it chunkwise with some chunk-size a fair dice-roll gave me.

Comment: In fact, this is the traditional method to copy a stream. A good buffer size depends on the specific situation, but probably it has to be a multiple of block size at very least. Remember, file sizes are among the things that easily go beyond 32 bit integer max value ;)

Comment: Yea, I've seen this method. but is it smart to pretend low-level in a language like C#? to get this right, you have to consider context switches, library io buffers, etc. Buffer-copying is low-level stuff and should be done on the low level, if you REALLY need it, which isn't the usual case.

Comment: @Nico, Smartness and simplicity are relative.

Comment: i got too much into this, hm? i'm sorry, i didn't mean to offend you.

Comment: @Nico, I don't how you interpreted my statement. I meant, the amount of simplicity and smartness depends on the situation. In this special case (using files), the performance of loading the whole files can be extremely critical which cannot always be ignored just because you're coding in C#.

Comment: Most cases, Jimmy's way of doing it is fine. If you have large files and need speed, reading from the output of "cat file1 file2 file3" is probably going to be faster than having the buffer on the C# side.

Comment: It might be but it has some other problems. Creating the process, introducing platform dependence, reliance on a third party program and making stuff more complex. You have to make these trade-offs and the "right" solution depends on the specific scenario.

Comment: I was thinking all the time why you think it's that much "low-level". I thought it might worth mentioning that FileStreams are internally buffered, so the array here is not doing any actual file buffering to reduce low level syscalls. It's just reducing method calls and it's not that low level.

Comment: Yea, but this is kind of my point: using these buffers looks low-level  and complicated, but actually it's above the library-buffer, which reads from the OS buffer, which reads from the disc buffer. if i want to use buffers, i do it low-level. if i want to attach files high-level, i do f1+f2+f3.

Comment: By the way, performance aside, unless you are dealing with text files, `ReadAllText` is definitely not the way to go. You can corrupt the contents of the files while reading them into strings.

Comment: A situation where you might want this kind of lower level approach is where you want to feedback progress to the user.

Answer (score 42):

I support Mehrdad Afshari on his code being exactly same as used in [System.IO.Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx).
I would still wonder why did he not use that same function instead of rewriting its implementation.

```
string[] srcFileNames = { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt" };
string destFileName = "destFile.txt";

using (Stream destStream = File.OpenWrite(destFileName))
{
    foreach (string srcFileName in srcFileNames)
    {
        using (Stream srcStream = File.OpenRead(srcFileName))
        {
            srcStream.CopyTo(destStream);
        }
    }
}
```

According to the disassembler ([ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx)) the default buffer size is 4096. CopyTo function has got an overload, which lets you specify the buffer size in case you are not happy with 4096 bytes.

Comment: Great answer.  This is just what I need.

Comment: Do I need to close `srcStream` with each file?

Comment: @rraallvv not when you are using `using` as OP wrote in his answer, then it is automatically cleaned up

Answer (score 7):

If your files are text and not large, there's something to be said for dead-simple, obvious code. I'd use the following.

```
File.ReadAllText("file1") + File.ReadAllText("file2") + File.ReadAllText("file3");
```

If your files are large text files and you're on Framework 4.0, you can use `File.ReadLines` to avoid buffering the entire file.

```
File.WriteAllLines("out", new[] { "file1", "file2", "file3" }.SelectMany(File.ReadLines));
```

If your files are binary, See [Mehrdad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/444316/4435)

Comment: disclaimer: will not work for large files. See Mehrdad Afshari's code for what to do then.

Comment: This looks like it will need a lot of memory to hold all three files in memory as a string, let alone the intermediate string object resulting by adding the first two and the final string created by adding on the last.

Comment: Jimmy you beat me to it with your own disclaimer! :)

Comment: 1) Concating strings are not good practise. You should use stringbuilder.

2) This is not good solution for binary files.

Comment: @TcKs: 1) inline concatenation here is done by string.concat(a,b,c) in one operation, with lower overhead than stringbuilder 2) I assumed "header/content/footer" files were text.

Comment: Note this will also rewrite your file as UTF-8 which may not be what is wanted, the above solution from user664769 that uses File.OpenRead operates on the bytes and therefore is a true concatenation of the files without worrying about encoding getting hammered.

Answer (score 6):

Another way....how about letting the OS do it for you?:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", 
        String.Format(@" /c copy {0} + {1} + {2} {3}", 
            file1, file2, file3, dest));
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process process = Process.Start(psi);
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: You let the OS do it no matter what, unless you're running on bare metal. But shelling out it something that shouldn't be done unless desperately needed.

Answer (score 3):

You mean 3 text files?? Does the result need to be a file again?

How about something like:

```
string contents1 = File.ReadAllText(filename1);
string contents2 = File.ReadAllText(filename2);
string contents3 = File.ReadAllText(filename3);

File.WriteAllText(outputFileName, contents1 + contents2 + contents3);
```

Of course, with a StringBuilder and a bit of extra smarts, you could easily extend that to handle any number of input files :-)

Cheers

Comment: This will force the contents of all the files to be loaded into memory.  If you have large files this is extremely inefficient as you will likely force objects into the large object heap.  Using a buffer will prevent the need for garbage collection and will almost certainly be more performant.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) environment, the most efficient solution could be to use the Win32 API function "WriteFile". There is an [example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165942) in VB 6, but rewriting it in C# is not difficult.