# How to dump the whole POST data to a file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, request, postdata

I'm currently trying to port an app from asp.net to php, however I just hit a wall and need a hand with this.

I need to dump all the data an .aspx recieves via POST to a file, but I have no clue on how to do this

any ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the InputStream property of the Request object.  This will give you the raw data of the http request.  Generally you might want to do this as a custom http handler, but I believe you can do it any time.

```
if (Request.RequestType == "POST")
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        // read the stream here using reader.ReadLine() and do your stuff.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you just want POST data, then you can use Request.Form.ToString() to get all the data in a url encoded manner.

```
if (Request.RequestType == "POST") {
    string myData = Request.Form.ToString();
    writeData(myData); //use the string to dump it into a file,
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `BinaryRead` to read from request body:

```
Request.BinaryRead
```

Or you could get a reference to input `Stream` object with:

```
Request.InputStream
```

Then you could use [`CopyStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444309/what-would-be-the-fastest-way-to-concatenate-three-files-in-c/444316#444316):

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(...))
    CopyStream(fs, Request.InputStream);
```

Comment: .NET 4.0 now has a `Stream.CopyTo()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a proxy application such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). This will let you look at all of the data that was transferred, as well as save it to a file as needed.

Comment: perfect, this shows all of the information sent and received!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is via some browser plugin like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [LiveHttpHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) (Firefox only). Then you can intercept the raw POST data.