# How can pause/resume recording audio from microphone in unity engine

Tags: unity-game-engine, microphone

In unity engine I want record audio from microphone with pause/resume ability; I want to have all of recorded audio in one AudioClip at final; and I don't know how many time it will pause and play (it's depend to user, not me) (also length of it) what can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have ready made solution, but the way you should start is to use [Microphone](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.html) class and use its `Start` and `End` function to record audio. This returns an audio clip which can be [save](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/354401/save-audio-to-a-file.html) to a numbered file (e.g., audio_datetime_00001,audio_datetime_00002,...). Once user Play/Pause/Stop you can create a new audio file. Later you can [merge them using NAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160888/how-do-i-merge-join-mp3-files-with-c) (try `Mark Heath's` solution).

Happy coding!!!