# how to download compressed file (.zip) through FTP using c#?

Tags: c#, ftp, sftp, ftpwebrequest

How to download .zip file format using c# code?

Here is the code, i am using to download. Just to highlight, If i download .txt file, it works fine. If i download .zip file, it downloads the .zip file but i can't open this. It complains that .zip is in incorrect format.  I have doubt in how i am writing back the file on local drive.

Help?

```
string ftpServerIP = FTPServer;
string ftpUserID = FTPUser;
string ftpPassword = FTPPwd;
FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(FileName);
string uri = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + fileInf.Name;
FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uri); //new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + DestinationFolder + fileInf.Name));
reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
reqFTP.EnableSsl = true;
reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
//reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
//Stream strm = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(reqFTP.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(FolderToWriteFiles, FileName), false);
writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
return true;
```

Comment: Is this any good: http://www.dijksterhuis.org/webclient-class-upload-download-ftp-files/

Comment: Is it safe to assume you've downloaded the file with a stand-alone FTP client and that it is a valid zip file?

Comment: @Austin Salonen. Zip file is a valid one. I can unzip that file on server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
using System.Net;
// ...

new WebClient().DownloadFile("ftp://ftp.someurl.com/file.zip",
                             "C:\\downloadedFile.zip");
```

---

#### Answer to the updated question:

The way you are saving the stream to disk is wrong. You are treating the stream as a character sequence, which corrupts the ZIP file in the process. Open a `FileStream` instead of a `StreamWriter` and copy the `GetResponseStream()` return value directly to that `FileStream` using something like [my `CopyStream` function from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444309/what-would-be-the-fastest-way-to-concatenate-three-files-in-c/444316#444316).

Comment: Can i do something using FtpWebRequest class?

Comment: This assumes the FTP server needs no login. The FtpWebRequest class would be better suited for an ftp server that requires a login.

Comment: @user144842: Yes, but `WebClient` abstracts it away. If you just need to download a file without any more control, use `WebClient`.

Comment: @rally25rs. My server needs login authentication.

Comment: @user144842: Then `WebClient` won't work for you. You need to use `WebRequest.Create` or `FtpWebRequest` directly (`WebClient` actually uses `WebRequest` internally, which is an abstract class that creates `XXXWebRequest` classes for different protocols.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: See my updated question/code above, and give me your best suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @user144842: commented on the question. Can you *download* the zip file with a FTP client (lets say Internet Explorer) and try opening it?

Comment: @user144842: I guess I noticed the problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: :( gtg. its already 5 here. i will try it next week. have a good weekend.

Comment: @Mehrdad. I am still stuck here. I could not use your example. Help?

Comment: @user144842: Why couldn't you use it? What's the problem? Instead of creating a StreamWriter, create a FileStream and copy GetResponseStream to the filestream.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I tried..but i really don't know how? I am Sorry if i am asking little too much, I need code :(?

Comment: Replace the last lines with `using (var fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(FolderToWriteFiles, FileName))) CopyStream(fs, reqFTP.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());` The `CopyStream` function is linked in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework's System.Net namespace offers the FTPWebRequest class.  Here's an article explaining how to use it:

http://www.vcskicks.com/download-file-ftp.php

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to make use of the [FtpWebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) to download the .zip file, then the [System.IO.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.aspx) class to extract its contents.

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative for unzipping is http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip.

If you need to download SSH or SSL encryption then I recommend this component: http://www.weonlydo.com/index.asp?showform=FtpDLX.NET. Also great for plain FTP.

Comment: This is what I use, and for zip files over FTP make sure you use FileStream!

Answer (score 0):

For all of you who found these answers unhelpful, I found a better answer here:

[Downloading ZIP file from FTP and copying to folder within website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451298/downloading-zip-file-from-ftp-and-copying-to-folder-within-website)