# How to download ZipFile From FTP server

Tags: c#, ftp

I have zip file in ftp server,this zip file contain more then one xml file in it,i want to download this zipfile and save to local disk,i have write below code,i download file but when i try to Extract this zip it throw me error that File is corrupted......

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_remoteHost + file);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_remoteUser, _remotePass);
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(destination);
writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());

writer.Close();
reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

Comment: You need to tell us more. Like, what language is this?

Comment: Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are channeling the result of the FTP request through a `StreamReader`.  This has the usually beneficial effect of handling character encoding, but is not something you ever want to do when dealing with binary data (i.e. a zip file).  Instead, you should read the data directly from the stream.  Something like:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_remoteHost + file);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_remoteUser, _remotePass);
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

// Copy the data from the responseStream to destination 1k at a time (feel free to increase buffer size)
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
for (int amountRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); amountRead > 0; amountRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))
{
    destination.Write(buffer, 0, amountRead);
}
destination.Flush();

response.Close();
```

Comment: Just for clarification, if you are returning this result into ASP.net page response then "destination" variable is the Page Response

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
Stream destination = Response.OutputStream;

Answer (score 1):

Here are sample code for Download file from FTP Server

```
Uri url = new Uri("ftp://ftp.demo.com/file1.txt");
if (url.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
{
    FtpWebRequest objRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(url);
    //Set credentials if required else comment this Credential code
    NetworkCredential objCredential = new NetworkCredential("FTPUserName", "FTPPassword");
    objRequest.Credentials = objCredential;
    objRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    FtpWebResponse objResponse = (FtpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    int len = 0;
    FileStream objFS = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("file1.txt"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
    while ((len = objReader.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        objFS.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    objFS.Close();
    objResponse.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is the way that you download the zip, here's an article explaining how to use it, i hope it helps:

http://www.vcskicks.com/download-file-ftp.php

Also, there is a question like this here:

[how to download compressed file (.zip) through FTP using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255227/how-to-download-compressed-file-zip-through-ftp-using-c)