# Efficient way to combine multiple text files

Tags: c#, performance, concatenation

I have multiple files of text that I need to read and combine into one file.
The files are of varying size: 1 - 50 MB each.
What's the most efficient way to combine these files without bumping into the dreading `System.OutofMemoryException`?

Comment: Can you describe 'Combine' ?  And what is in those files? Just lines of text or CSV or XML or ...

Comment: What kind of combining are you needing to do? If you're just, say, merge-sorting a bunch of sorted files, you won't need to read the whole files into memory, but can just process them line-by-line.

Comment: from  a command prompt: copy <your files> targefile.text

Comment: Yeah... copy file1.txt + file2.txt + file3.txt allfiles.txt

Comment: There's a previous discussion of this topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444309/what-would-be-the-fastest-way-to-concatenate-three-files-in-c.  Looks like that's a nice approach that will not use as much RAM as looping `ReadAllText` then `WriteAllText`.

Comment: `copy *.txt allfiles.txt`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Do it in chunks:

```
const int chunkSize = 2 * 1024; // 2KB
var inputFiles = new[] { "file1.dat", "file2.dat", "file3.dat" };
using (var output = File.Create("output.dat"))
{
    foreach (var file in inputFiles)
    {
        using (var input = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to run to a meeting and might not be able to test for a bit, but I'll get back to you ASAP! - Thanks

Comment: The repeated reallocation of, and data copy to, `actual` is redundant. Just write out the number of bytes you know you read (per `bytesread`) directly from `buffer` to the new file. `buffer` itself also only needs to be allocated once, before entering the outer `for` loop.

Comment: @Steve Townsend, very good point. I've updated my post to take it into account.

Comment: Darin, thanks.  Much appreciated.  10 files and it doesn't even break a sweat.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov does this handle unicode files too? what if two files are in a different format?

Comment: @Baz1nga It copies things as is, so the encoding doesn't matter. If the files have different encodings though, the resulting file will not be properly displayed by a normal editor.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Slight improvement: do `new byte[chunkSize]` only once instead of for each file, and use `chunkSize` instead of `buffer.length`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov would merging it in memory in parallel (using memory stream) and then writing to the disk, make it any faster?

Answer (score 23):

Darin is on the right track. My tweak would be:

```
using (var output = File.Create("output"))
{
    foreach (var file in new[] { "file1", "file2" })
    {
        using (var input = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            input.CopyTo(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `CopyTo` is a nice one but it's probably worth mentioning that it's only available in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Oooo - didn't now that. My MSDN defaults to .NET 4

Comment: how do we get the files back from the combined file ?

Comment: @Carter: Could you clarify? The original files still exist

Comment: Yes, in my case i have two files "file.Docx" and "file_Information.Xml" i want the application A for example to merge the two in one single file "file.QAF"...
then pass this file to another application B to recover the two files "file.Docx" and "file_Information.Xml" (the way back...)

Comment: @CarterNolan just make a note of the length of each file (i.e. input.Length) and then pass it on to application B. Inside application B when writing with FileStream.Write,  set offset to the starting byte of each file and count to the number of bytes to write.

Answer (score 1):

This is code used above for .Net 4.0, but compatible with .Net 2.0 (for text files)

```
using (var output = new StreamWriter("D:\\TMP\\output"))
{
  foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles("D:\\TMP", "*.*"))
  {
    using (var input = new StreamReader(file))
    {
      output.WriteLine(input.ReadToEnd());
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that this will read the entire file in memory at once. This means that large files will cause a lot of memory to be used (and if not enough memory is available, it may fail all together).

Comment: -1: This won't work for big files (cause `ReadToEnd()` will create a string in memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
copy *.txt <combined_fileName>.txt
```

I also think this is best approach. Within 3 hours combined 450+ files and with excel removed unwanted records, like file-header, footer etc.