# combine two word documents into one

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I tried the solution in [Combine multiple files into single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524909/combine-multiple-files-into-single-file), however only first file is being shown on combined document. I also tried the solution mentioend here [What would be the fastest way to concatenate three files in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444309/what-would-be-the-fastest-way-to-concatenate-three-files-in-c), it seems .txt files are working fine, however I am unable to combine two .doc files into one .doc file. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: .doc files are binary, not text. Simply concatenating them won't work. You'll need a library that understands the format.

Comment: We used ASPOSE api to manuplate word documents https://www.aspose.com/products/words/net