# Using the copy command in c#, not respecting paths

Tags: c#, copy, command

I am trying to code something that will essentially concat a bunch of files together into 1 output file.

my code is as follows

```
string[] destination = new string[this.lbFiles.Items.Count];
this.lbFiles.Items.CopyTo(destination, 0);
string result1 = ConvertStringArrayToString(destination);
result1 = result1.Remove(result1.Length - 3);
string outputfile = this.saveFileDialog1.FileName;
string copyarg = "copy /b " + result1 + quote + outputfile + quote;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", copyarg);
```

So basically result1 = all the files i'm trying to concatenate.  with full paths and quotes.  and outputfile = the output file name i want to use with full path.

My problem is, when I execute the code, it copys the files, but it doesnt use the output file name I have specified, and it outputs the file to the directory where the program exe is located, not the path I have specified.

Any help?

Comment: Why aren't you using `File.Copy` and its friends?

Comment: @TDaver probably because the command-line version can be used to concatenate files, while File.Copy cannot. That said, `cmd copy /b` is still the wrong way to do this. Just open an output stream and read in from each file, write back to the output.

Comment: But C# has it's fair share of tricks for concatting too. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444309/what-would-be-the-fastest-way-to-concatenate-three-files-in-c

Comment: @Derek - what is the value of copyarg when you call Process.Start?

Comment: /C copy /b "d:\test1.ac3" + "d:\test2.ac3" "d:\output.ac3"

that would be the value of copyarg

Comment: I have a bunch of files in a listbox. I copy them into a string array, and then turn that string array into a string that contains "file1" + "file2" etc...i then feed that into the cmd copy process. my problem is, it's not respecting the full path

Comment: I think you're either missing a quote in there, or a space.   You're removing the last three characters of `result1`, which I assume are space-plus-space, and then immediately adding a quote.  This would produce `copy /b "d:\test1.ac3" + "d:\test2.ac3""d:\output.ac3"`.  I have no idea what that would do if you ran it, though.

Comment: Bobson you are a genius! that was it! i changed it to remove 2 characters instead and it works!  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Derek - Glad it helped!  I added it as an answer so you can accept it if you choose.  Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be either missing a quote in there, or a space. You're removing the last three characters of result1, which I assume are "`+`", and then immediately adding a quote. This would produce `copy /b "d:\test1.ac3" + "d:\test2.ac3""d:\output.ac3"`.

I would assume this would error, but if it doesn't, it could certainly produce your odd behavior.  Especially if your file names actually have spaces in them.